# Segmentation fault debian 8 golang

Tags: linux, go, segmentation-fault, debian

tstx program code (golang)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
 fmt.Printf("Hello")
}
```

On dev computer (debian based linux) all ok, but 
when i run it on server computer (Debian 8) i got segmentation fault

both systems are amd64, code compilled with [go build]

[strace ./tstx] - says

```
execve("./tstx", ["./tstx"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0                                                                                                                                                                  
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xffffffffffffff8b} ---                                                                                                                                
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

Comment: Is this with go1.7? What is your "debian based linux"?

Comment: yes, go1.7, my linux - kali

Comment: Are you compiling the program on the debian machine, or are you copying the binary from the kali machine? I would start with the go mailing list or open an issue. This isn't really the place for for debugging language runtime or OS bugs.

Comment: Im copying from kali to debian

Comment: Yes, I would suspect kali is doing something stringe, but I'm not sure what offhand. This is probably better suited for a go-specific forum.

Comment: Just now, I tried to compile on windows 10 with go1.6.3, now i got(on debian):      

execve("./test", ["./test"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0                                                                                         
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x584f07)       = 0                                                                                               
--- SIGTRAP {si_signo=SIGTRAP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---                                                                                     
+++ killed by SIGTRAP +++

Answer (score 2):

Since you're compiling on one machine and moving to another, you'll really want to be sure that DLLs aren't an issue.  First, build with:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build...
```

And ensure it looks good with:

```
ldd tstx
```

(It should come back with "not a dynamic executable" or similar).

Disabling CGO means that the executable will be larger (everything statically linked), but dlls won't be an issue since it's self-contained.  Finally, it can't hurt to verify that their architectures are the same via uname...